# Supabase file uploading occasionally fails

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

Sometimes I can upload a file and sometimes I get this error:

```
{statusCode: '403', error: '', message: 'new row violates row-level security policy (USING expression) for table "objects"'}
```

I got the uploading code from [this page](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-nextjs). I duplicated the component with different bucket names and only changed `htmlFor`, `id`, `accept` and bucket url, both with the same policies but sometimes the other works/fails or both. One is for image upload and the other video, both have worked at some point so idk why I keep getting the error. And none of the files exceeds the max upload size(50mb). Heres SQL snippet I used:

```
insert into storage.buckets (id, name)
  values ('avatars', 'avatars');

create policy "Avatar images are publicly accessible." on storage.objects
  for select using (bucket_id = 'avatars');

create policy "Anyone can upload an avatar." on storage.objects
  for insert with check (bucket_id = 'avatars');
```

Also I'm using Typescript and no error in my code.

Comment: Do you have a certain combination of policies and frontend code that fails persistently?